# Center text to page not cell

Tags: html, css

I have a sticky footer bar thanks to the folks at [cssstickyfooter](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html) which holds a disclaimer. I wanted to put a facebook like button on the right hand side... so I created a table with the below code for the footer.

```
#footer {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -60px;
    height: 60px;
    clear:both;
    background-color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    color: #999;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

and the html as

```
<div id="footer">
<table width="100%">
<tr>
    <td width="85%">
        <p>© 2011 somecompany<br />
        Image © 2011 by somebig company</p>
    </td>
    <td width="15%">
        <p>like goes here</p>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

This (obviously) aligns the the text, but it aligns it to the cell that it is in. Is there anyway to align the disclaimer text to the center of the whole page and keep the like button to the right?

I have thought about just putting the like button in its own table and have that floating there... but I'm not sure.

Theres a jsfiddle example over at http://jsfiddle.net/Gnznn/

Thanks!

*Marked as homework so I can get an explaination*

Comment: You're using `table`s for layout?

Comment: @JaredFarrish yeah it was the first thing to come to mind when I did it (:

Comment: Don't use `table`s for layout is a good place to start; it's generally considered a bad technique. Also, your question is lacking any actual example. Can you http://jsfiddle.net a demo?

Comment: @JaredFarrish alrighty i got a jsfiddle done at http://jsfiddle.net/Gnznn/

Comment: [You don't need a `table` for that](http://jsfiddle.net/Gnznn/2/).

Comment: @JaredFarrish sure ok but it still [doesn't center my text :(](http://jsfiddle.net/6S4nT/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling there is a cleaner* way to do this, but this at least works and does *not* use `table`s for layout. Note, I put the styles in an attribute so you could see what I was doing easier, but you should put that in your declarations in relevant classes.

```
<div id="footer">
    <div style="width: 15%; height: 1px; float: left;"></div>
    <div style="width: 70%; float: left;">
        <p>© 2011 somecompany<br />Image © 2011 by somebig company</p>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 15%; float: right;">
        <p>like goes here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Gnznn/3/

* In other words, using `position: relative` or `position: absolute`  with `right: 0` and `z-index: 5000` (or something).